# Spring Scheduler not working when used on the Interface method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a interface method annotated with `@Scheduled` annotation with a cron expression. I am expecting the class that implements the interface and overrides the method should have the scheduler functionality from the interface but that's not the case? Can anyone explain me why? Is there another solution to achieve this functionality?

Interface:

```
@Component

    public interface TestInterface {

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * *")
        public void testScheduler();
     }
```

Implementation Class:

```
@RestController
public class Controller implements TestInterface {

    @Override
    public void testScheduler() {
        System.out.println("Test Scheduler implemented");   
    }

}
```

Comment: Java specifies that annotations aren't inherited from interfaces. For some annotations Spring itself checks the interfaces but not for `@Scheduled`. You should really put it on the implementation (as it should be part of the implementation, not the contract imho).

Comment: I need to have the method which reads the @scheduled annotation in the parent class and should be implemented in the child class. Is there a achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Then why use interfaces. Also why would you need it in a parent class? If that is what you want do it and simply delegate to an `abstract` method that child classes need to implement.

Comment: If I make the class and method as abstract, then I am not able to read the properties from external properties file

Comment: I am reading the property from the external property file using spring.config.location. I want to read the property like this @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.cron.expression}")
        public void testScheduler();

Comment: And what would be the difference with an interface? You would still have the same issue. Again you should put it on the actual implementation then not an abstract class nor interface will help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments by [M.Denium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), the annotation is **not** inherited from the interface method. You need to add the annotation on the bean implementation as Spring will only scan the beans for the @Scheduled annotation.